# Windows 7 CoreAudio Media Foundation- uuidof of IID_IAudioStreamVolume

Tags: windows, audio, ms-media-foundation

I'm getting a link error for the following code:

hr = pPlaybackClient->GetService(IID_IAudioStreamVolume, (void **)&pStreamVolume);

The link error is "Unresolved external symbol _IID_IAudioStreamVolume"

IID_IAudioStreamVolume is defined in Audioclient.h, and I am #including that file.  If I declare:

const IID IID_IAudioStreamVolume = __uuidof(IID_IAudioStreamVolume);

I get "error: operand of __uuidof must have a class or enum type for which __declspec(uuid('...')) has been specified.

I'm sure this is a minor problem, but I don't see the answer- help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.  Using __uuidof(IAudioStreamVolume) instead of IID_IAudioStreamVolume allows it to compile and link properly.  If anybody knows where I can find some documentation with regards to what MS is doing here I would appreciate it.

Comment: `IID_IAudioStreamVolume` is not in SDK. Yes you can easiyl work it around with `__uuidof` as you already found. I suppose the documentation writes assumed that IID_ variable will be additionally available as well (as it happens with others).

Comment: Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: `__uuidof` is certainly documented. Moreover all interfaces in Windows SDK have IIDs attached and you can apply __uuidof... Except for the oldest where you have use `IID_` prefix explicitly.